# Remove the post_content search from WHERE clause (and CONCAT sql function)

Tags: filters, search, posts-where

I've a custom table and by following the instructions on this page https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries I was able to modify the WHERE clause.

```
function geotag_search_where( $where ){
   if( is_search() ) {
         $where = preg_replace( "/\(\s*" . $wpdb->posts . ".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
         " CONCAT( posts.post_title, customtable.customfield) LIKE $1 ", $where );
      }

   return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'geotag_search_where' );
```

My only problem is that wordpress keeps the `OR (posts.post_content LIKE '%searchterm%')` and this slows down my search time. Is there a way to modify the `preg_replace()` so that it will exclude also the post_content? Thanks!

EDIT [as per @Prosti request]

Here is how is now my WHERE clause

```
SELECT [normal select from worpress] 
 ….
[customized from my filters]
LEFT JOIN customtable ON FIND_IN_SET(posts.ID, customtable.postID) >0 
WHERE 1=1 
AND (term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (7) ) 
AND (( CONCAT(posts.post_title, customtable.customfield) LIKE '%searchterm%' 
    OR (posts.post_content LIKE '%searchterm%'))) 
[end of customization]
 ……. 
AND [rest is normal from worpress]
```

I would like to exclude the `OR (posts.post_content LIKE '%searchterm%')`

so that sql would be:

```
....
AND (( CONCAT(posts.post_title, customtable.customfield) LIKE '%searchterm%' ))
....
```

Comment: why do you use `preg_replace`, this may be the slow down-er. Usually these filters just append a condition or two with AND .... Can you reorganize the where?

Comment: @Prosti Thanks, I did test the query in phpMyadmin and it's the `OR (posts.post_content LIKE` that slows down the query, up to 3 minutes!! Prosti, do you know if there is a where parameter to enter in the $args for the WP_Query or can you point me to a good tutorial for customize the sql of the wordpress search? Most of the tutorial don't explains how to include custom DB tables. ... it's 3 days I'm searching for something. I'm open to any suggestion/solution. Thanks

Comment: You need to provide one example of the SQL query you get at the very end. It is hard to comment otherwise.

Comment: So how do you achieve `CONCAT`?

Comment: `Most of the tutorial don't explain how to include custom DB tables` WordPress is not meant to work with custom db tables, my friend.

Comment: It's in my filter `$where = preg_replace(
            "/\(\s*" . $wpdb->posts . ".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
            " CONCAT( " . $wpdb->posts . ".post_title, customtable.customfield) LIKE $1 ", $where );` Like the example in my question from https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries

Comment: So your question need [edit]. There was no `CONCAT` in there.

Comment: Alright, done, but I still need to exclude `OR (posts.post_content LIKE '%searchterm%')` from my WHERE clause. Can you help me with that?

Comment: So your question is still without `CONCAT`? [edit] it and don't provide the details in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

First look how complex is your preg replace. Usually, you may get into errors with that.

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  post_title               'post_title'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  LIKE                     'LIKE'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \'                       '''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\']+                   any character except: '\'' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \'                       '''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /",       "              '/",       "'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    post_title LIKE          'post_title LIKE '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                        '1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   OR                      ' OR '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    geotag_city LIKE         'geotag_city LIKE '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                        '1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   OR                      ' OR '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \4:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    geotag_state LIKE        'geotag_state LIKE '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                        '1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                OR         '              OR '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \5:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    geotag_country           'geotag_country LIKE '
    LIKE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                        '1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \5
```

Next, you need to provide **full** SQL query example after `preg_replace` .

If we can have the full SQL query, we may also understand the customization.

Looking at what you wrote we need to have the arguments you set for the WP_Query, to understand how you organized the query.

More, `CONCAT` is not a smart thing in there, it forces MySQL to concatenate strings — a slow down factor.

Hope this may be helpful.

Comment: Your question still lacks information.

Comment: Edited again, title and question, let me know if you need more info. A part of that filter, there is nothing else I did. PS I tested the CONCAT in phpMyadmin and, in my case, it doesn't slow down the query.